# Telling numberOfRowsInSection how many rows it needs after parsing JSON with JSONDecoder in closure using MVVM architecture

Tags: swift, generics, tableview, jsondecoder

I'm using MMVM architecture.

Basically I have this function to parse JSON in a viewModelProtocol extension as default implementation, my viewModels are conforming to this protocol. Most viewModels populate standard Views without any problem except for one that is populating a tableVIew but I can't tell numberOfRowsInSection how many rows it needs.

```
func setWithJSON<T>(completion: @escaping (T) -> Void, error: @escaping (Error) -> Void, service: Services) where T : Decodable {
    let failure: (Error) -> Void = { error in
        self.dataFetchError?(error)
    }

    let completion: (Data) -> Void = { data in

        do {
            let parsedJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(parsedJSON)
        } catch {
            self.dataFetchError?(error)
        }
        return
    }

    QueryAPI.shared.setServiceURL(service)
    QueryAPI.shared.fetchData(failure: failure, completion: completion)
}
```

With it I'm getting a generic type of parsedJSON

I'm using the function in my view to populate my cells in the cellForRowAt indexPath: method like this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier") as! ExperienceViewCell

    let error: (Error) -> Void = { error in
        self.handleError(error)
    }

    let completion: ([Experience]) -> Void = { experiences in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [ weak cell ] in
            cell?.companyLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].company
            cell?.positionLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].position
            cell?.websiteLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].website
            cell?.startDateLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].startDate
            cell?.endDateLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].endDate
            cell?.summaryTextView.text = experiences[indexPath.row].summary
            cell?.highLightsTextView.text = experiences[indexPath.row].highlights
        }
    }

    viewModel.setWithJSON(completion: completion, error: error, service: .workExperience)
    self.viewModel.dataFetchError = { error in
        self.handleError(error)
    }

    return cell
}
```

This way I'm getting an array of the struct Experience in the closure and I use every one of its elements to populate the rows of my tableView.

But I don't have a way to tell the method numberOfRowsInSection how many rows do we need so I'm hardcoding it but that's not what I need.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}
```

Is there any way I can get an array of Experience when the view loads so I can tell the method how many rows it should return.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that you are calling the service in the `tableView:cellForRowAt:` function and this is not a good approach.

Try to set in your viewController a variable `var experiences: [Experience] = []`

In the `viewDidLoad` function call your service

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let completion: ([Experience]) -> Void = { experiences in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [ weak self ] in
            self?.experiences = experiences
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    viewModel.setWithJSON(completion: completion, error: error, service: .workExperience)
    self.viewModel.dataFetchError = { error in
        self.handleError(error)
    }
}
```

In the function `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you can return `experiences.count`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return experiences.count
}
```

And finally, inside function `tableView:cellForRowAt:` you can put your code to update the cell:

```
cell.companyLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].company
cell.positionLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].position
cell.websiteLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].website
cell.startDateLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].startDate        
cell.endDateLabel.text = experiences[indexPath.row].endDate
cell.summaryTextView.text = experiences[indexPath.row].summary
cell.highLightsTextView.text = experiences[indexPath.row].highlights
```

With `tableView.reloadData()`, you will call again the function `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` after you receive your list of experiences.

Comment: Yes, that did it!, I couldn't use the default generic implementation of setWithJSON that I had in my protocol for that view, but after using a specific one built for this view it worked like a charm. Thanks